# Search Page Returns Nothing

Tags: wp-query, search

I'm currently working on this [website](http://pba.siteprogression.com/) and a test shows that the search page isn't working properly. Every time someone  searches for something, it comes up blank. The code for the search page is as shown below.

**Search Form:**

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="/search/" >
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="image" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/searcher1.png"id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

**Search Page:**

```
<?php
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'search' ] ) ) {
        // run search query
        query_posts( array(
            's' => $_REQUEST[ 'search' ],
            'post_type' => $_REQUEST[ 'post_type' ],

        ) );

        // loop
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) :
            // loop through results here
        endwhile; endif;

        // return to original query
        wp_reset_query();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `action="/search/"` to `action="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ) ?>"`

Comment: There's [`home_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/home_url/) for that ;)

Comment: Dead Medic, That didn't solve the problem, it didn't even go to the search page at all.

Comment: @kaiser `bloginfo( 'url' )` escapes & outputs `home_url()` - problem?

Comment: @Dz.slick Well it should, since `http://example.com/?s=search` is treated as a search query :s

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Problem? No. Not in every case. But this fn A) applies the filter and B) takes takes `https://`-situations into account. [Not that this would work in every case](https://gist.github.com/1891564)

Comment: @kaiser I know. Like I say, `bloginfo( 'url' )` calls `home_url()`, escapes it for output, & displays it === `echo esc_attr( home_url() )`

Comment: My bad - doesn't escape, just outputs ;)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Nothing bad :) It offers an additional filter. So maybe it should be used in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You only need this part on your search page, delete all the rest

```
// loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // loop through results here
endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: +1. Get rid of the `query_posts()` call, and call `the_post()` as part of the Loop. To test: remove/rename `search.php`, and see if the search results render properly via the fallback, `index.php`. If they do, then your problem is `query_posts()` and the lack of `the_post()`.

Comment: Chip I did that and it still didn't work.

Comment: If you try something, can you update your original question with 1) what you tried, 2) what happened/didn't happen? Since I suggested 2 things, I don't know which you tried, or what happened when you tried it.